# Looking for Win95 game with vector graphic

Tags: windows-95, identify-this-game

The game I can't remember the name of was like this:

You controlled a triangular space-ship which could fly from planet to planet and could land on it. The planets had gravity which made it not so easy to land on them.

So its not like asteroid where you can fly only in a limited area, you could fly around.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing!  Hopefully one of our users can answer the question.  In the meantime, feel free to browse around and see if there are any questions you can answer.  You can also check out the [tour](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge.

Comment: Was it a Windows or a DOS game? Do you remember roughly what the screen looked like during gameplay / at the menu? Do you have any images and, if not, do you remember what it looked like well enough to sketch some? You don't need to answer all of these questions, but it would certainly help us if we had a bit more information!

Comment: It isn't the game named *"Elite"*?

Comment: a good resource for this kind of question is https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/

Comment: @Janka - *Elite* didn't feature landing on planets, although *Frontier - Elite II* and *Frontier - First Encounters* both did ... but had more elaborate graphics that don't really sound like the description.

Answer (score 5):

Gravity Well? It seems to meet all your criteria.

As described by the game's help files:

> Gravity Well is a fast paced game of planetary conquest for Windows 95 or Windows NT. It is a strategic war game that is played like an arcade game. The game represents a simple interstellar economy that supports the discovery and conquest of new worlds. The player's role is to scout new planets and establish landing sites for the colonization ships that follow. Once a landing site is established, freighters will be dispatched to begin construction of a base and colony complex. Beware though, you are not alone. There are others with the same designs on this sector of space as you have. Be prepared to fight for every stinking dirtball.

[image: Game screenshot: a freighter is transporting material to a recently claimed planet]
[image: Game screenshot: the blue player tries to damage a base owned by the red player]

Here's a gameplay video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPrAPJRMtIU

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Thanks for posting a second answer, but as I have commented on the other answer it would be very useful if you added some more description of the gameplay and added some screenshots. Also, reading the [tour] wouldn't help; (we're a little bit different from other sites*, you see...

Comment: The description from the game's own help files describe it well in my opinion. Is it appropriate to copy and paste that here?

Comment: If you provide attribution, yes. In fact, that would be ideal! Just say something like "As described by the game's help files, it is:" then press "Enter" twice (for a paragraph break), paste it in and put `>` at the beginning of the quote (to trigger the `<blockquote>` formatting).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You've really improved the post. Now the OP can see whether this game is the one they thought without clicking on extra links; well done!

Answer (score 2):

I thinking that might be a game called Gravitar. It was similar to Lunar Lander, but with a little more to do. Here's the Wikipedia link --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitar.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing!  Make sure to check out the [tour](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your first badge.

Comment: This could be the game that the OP is looking for; it certainly matches the description. This answer could be improved by adding some more information; at present one has to click on the Wikipedia link to get a description of the gameplay.

Comment: I was exactly thinking about these two; they've been ported to almost every system in existence :)